# How to Pivot a group of columns as rows in output

Tags: ssis, flat-file

i am trying to convert a file with layout as follows:

```
id1 | id2 | id3 |...| id34 | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C | 100 group of A B C|
a1  | b1  | c1  |...| aa1  | 3 | 7 | 5 | 7 | 5 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ...               |
a2  | b2  | c2  |...| aa2  | 4 | 3 | 7 | 0 | 4 | 8 | 9 | 8 | 4 | ...               |
```

Output should be:

```
id1 | id2 | id3 |...| id34 | A | B | C |
a1  | b1  | c1  |...| aa1  | 3 | 7 | 5 |
a1  | b1  | c1  |...| aa1  | 7 | 5 | 3 |
a1  | b1  | c1  |...| aa1  | 1 | 1 | 1 |
a2  | b2  | c2  |...| aa1  | 4 | 3 | 7 |
a2  | b2  | c2  |...| aa1  | 0 | 4 | 8 |
a2  | b2  | c2  |...| aa1  | 9 | 8 | 4 |
```

i'm currently doing it through Script transformation Component
but its very slow.

i am not very familiar with the Pivot and Unpivot Component

Is there any option which can set the group of rows `| A | B | C |`
and SSIS will consider it as one set and convert it in my desired format?

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!

Comment: Pretty sure a script transformation is the way to go here. How slow are we talking here? What C# string manipulation functions are you using to split the rows up? It may be that your code can be improved to boost performance. Is the data in a fixed-length format? Or the pipe separation is how the fields are defined?

Comment: I'm currently doing like `myoutputBuffer.id1 = Row.id1;` i'm just pulling set of ids in row along with respective A B C then next row same set of ids and next set of A B C and so on, i'm doing a conversion also `myoutputBuffer.A = Convert.Toint32(Row.A)` actully m loading the data to SQL SERVER so i need to convert to Int, my input data is Pipe seperated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first load the file "as is" into a wide SQL table.  I would number the columns groups e.g.

`id1 | id2 | id3 |...| id34 | A | B | C | A | B | C | A | B | C | ...|
a1  | b1  | c1  |...| aa1  | 3 | 7 | 5 | 7 | 5 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ...  |`

... loads into columns ...

`id1 | id2 | id3 |...| id34 | A1 | B1 | C1 | A2 | B2 | C2 | A3 | B3 | C3 | ...
a1  | b1  | c1  |...| aa1  | 3  | 7  | 5  | 7  | 5  | 3  | 1  | 1  | 1  | ...   |`

Then I would create a Variable (String) to hold a dynamic SQL statment, driven by another Variable (Int).  I would create a For Each Loop to increment the Int Variable from 1 to 100.  Within the loop I would use the String Variable to drive a Data Source.

The first iteration, the SQL would look like:

`SELECT id1, id2, id3 ... id34, A1 AS A, B1 AS B, C1 AS C
FROM Staging_Table`

2nd iteration, the SQL would look like this:

`SELECT id1, id2, id3 ... id34, A2 AS A, B2 AS B, C2 AS C
FROM Staging_Table`

... and so on.

The output from each iteration would go via an OLE DB Destination into the target table.